# Can I force git to treat a change as a single piece?

Tags: git, diff

Occasionally I'll have a commit that completely rewrites a block of code, but has a few identical lines interspersed by chance. Git-diff divides the change into pieces around those lines, and the diff becomes hard to understand.

In such cases it would be nice to tell git "ignore single unchanged lines; act as if this entire block was deleted and replaced."

For example, I want to turn a diff that looks like this:

```
-def rewritten_function(oldarg):
-    do a
-    do b
+def rewritten_function(newarg):
+    do z
+    do y
     with random_matching_line as f:
-        do x
-        do y
-        do z
+        do a
+        do b
+        do c
```

into this:

```
-def rewritten_function(oldarg):
-    do a
-    do b
-    with random_matching_line as f:
-        do x
-        do y
-        do z
+def rewritten_function(newarg):
+    do z
+    do y
+    with random_matching_line as f:
+        do a
+        do b
+        do c
```

Is there a way to do that, either when preparing a commit or viewing the log later?

Answer (score 1):

`diff.interHunkContext`'s config says

> Show the context between diff hunks, up to the specified number of lines,
>      thereby fusing the hunks that are close to each other. This value serves as
>      the default for the `--inter-hunk-context` command line option.

which looks like exactly what you want.

Comment: I don't think it is...if I'm reading that right, it affects which changes are considered part of the same hunk; but I'm concerned with the display of the add/removes within what's already one hunk. Experimenting with it hasn't gotten me anywhere either. Maybe I should come up with a simplified example to add to the question.

Comment: I see it now, the word "hunk" just has too much work to do, I was thinking of potential-conflict ranges, which can be separated by single matching lines, which aren't the same as what diff calls a hunk, that generally need three.  An example would probably have helped.  I don't know how to do what you're after, I suspect that'd be a welcome patch..